# Правильное с точки зрения дизайна расширение функциональности классов

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, проектирование

Имеются следующие интерфейсы:

```
interface ITask {
  void Run();
}

interface ILogger{
  void Log(string message);
}
```

Для части классов, реализующих интерфейс ITask, необходимо иметь возможность писать данные в лог в процессе выполнения метода Run, используя экземпляр класса ILogger. При этом внутри реализации метода Run могут создаваться другие объекты ITask, и некоторые из них также должны иметь возможность использовать объект ILogger для логирования.

Как решить эту задачу наилучшим образом с точки зрения принципов проектирования ПО?

Мое решение следующее. Создать интерфейс:

```
interface IHasLogger {
  ILogger Logger { get; set; }
}
```

Реализовать этот интерфейс в тех классах, реализующих ITask, которым нужен функционал логирования. В методе Run при создании других экземпляров ITask проверять, реализует ли созданный объект интерфейс IHasLogger, и, если да, назначать его свойству Logger соответствующий объект-логгер.

Comment: ИМХО сильно зависит от языка программирования

Comment: Дизайн не должен зависеть от ЯП. В данном случае это C#, но вопрос общий для любого типичного ООП-языка.

Comment: @DarkGenius, я думаю, не правильно хранить экземпляр логгера в Task. Во-первых, допустим, у вас есть Task, который не логгирует сам по себе, но создает дочерние таски, которые должны логгировать - откуда он возьмет экземпляр логгера? Во-вторых, во время выполнения вы захотите изменить логгирование - начать писать в консоль вместо файла, как поступить? Для всех созданных тасков начать подменять логгер? Думаю, более правильно воспользоваться одним из порождающих шаблонов и, при необходимости логгирования, обратиться к объекту ответственному за создание/выдачу логгеров и получить логгер у него.

Comment: @Андрей, хороший вариант, спасибо. Правда, у него тоже есть недостаток: родительские задачи не могут сообщать дочерним, нужно ли вести логирование, если дочерняя задача сама будет запрашивать логгер и использовать его.

Comment: А включение/отключение логирования у вас глобальное или локально для каждой конкретной задачи?

Comment: @Андрей, в моем конкретном проекте подразумевается, что логирование включено глобально, но хотелось бы проектировать максимально гибко.

Comment: Ну раз глобально - вы просто переключаете свою фабрику (или что там будет у вас выдавать логгеры) на другой "нулевой" логгер (см. паттерн NullObject). В любом случае, я не специалист и это моё видение, мой вариант решения вашей задачи.